# Slicing an Array in android (Java) using Eclipse

Tags: android, slice

I'm trying to extract a specific string value from my array (the 'name' value), so that I can use it to load up the desired Activity.

```
rArr[i] = ("#" + entry + "    " + name);
```

I'm using an onListItemClick (listener) so I need to be able to extract the name from each item clicked, and then use it to load the corresponding xml file.

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String lItem = rArr[position];
```

So what I need to do is make lItem = rArr[position] but somehow extract the name from this array string.

I was wondering if there is a slicing function in Eclipse that I could make use of?
perhaps something similar to Pythons slicing?

Thank you for any help given.

Comment: I didn't really understand, can you explain it little more further? or an example?

Comment: Why don't you use a hashmap?

Comment: I *think* you want either `String.split()` or regular expressions.

Comment: If you want to extract part of the string, use the substring and indexof methods on it.

Comment: OP: thank you for the suggestions - i'll try some things out and update my post.

Comment: OP:Was just wondering. If I use another array to hold the name value at each point of the list - and then add this to the displayed text:
rArr[i] = ("#" + entry + "    " + names[i]);
Would I be able to then use this in the onListItemClick:
String lItem = names[position]

Just curious. Even if the listener is listening for click on the rArr entries it will relay this position and then pass the string from names - would that not be easier?

Comment: OP: I really appreciate the help guys. Think I need to go do some more reading on how this stuff works though. Not sure what I'm doing wrong by I feel that I should make sure I understand the SQLite a little more first. Cheers